# Plotting multiple series with ListLinePlot

Tags: plotting, legending, error-tracking

I would like to plot 2 series of data on a ListLinePlot. One is made up of a single line, one is split. Each one would ideally be separately coloured lines and noted in the legend.

I think I've managed to transfer most of my code for a single series into a plot with two, and I can get the points to appear and the calculations to complete and the epilog appear, but not the actual line.

Can anyone help me with getting the line / legend to appear? I believe the problem is likely something to do with how the brackets are laid out near where it says `LineLinePlot[{set[1]}`

```
  dataSet = {{63, 1.26}, {92, 1.74}, {156, 1.88}, {250, 2.33}, {317, 
    2.69}, {351, 2.85}, {357, 3.42}, {391, 3.43}, {422, 3.44}};
dataSet2 = {{50, 0.55}, {167, 1.6}, {169, 2.47}, {182, 3.2}, {227, 
    3.32}, {232, 3.39}, {262, 3.91}, {281, 1.26}, {310, 1.74}, {374, 
    1.88}, {468, 2.33}, {535, 2.69}, {575, 3.42}, {609, 3.43}, {640, 
    3.44}};

set[1] = Cases[dataSet, {x_, y_} /; x < 423];
set[2] = Cases[dataSet2, {x_, y_} /; x < 263];
set[3] = Cases[dataSet2, {x_, y_} /; x > 264];


avgCurrent = 
 Integrate[
     Interpolation[dataSet, InterpolationOrder -> 1][x], {x, 
      dataSet[[1, 1]], dataSet[[-1, 1]]}]/(Subtract @@ 
      dataSet[[{-1, 1}, 1]]) // N // SetPrecision[#, 3] &
maxCurrent = MaximalBy[dataSet, Last][[1, 2]];
noPoints = Length[dataSet];
lifeTime = dataSet[[-1, 1]];

avgCurrent2 = 
 Integrate[
     Interpolation[dataSet2, InterpolationOrder -> 1][x], {x, 
      dataSet2[[1, 1]], dataSet2[[-1, 1]]}]/(Subtract @@ 
      dataSet2[[{-1, 1}, 1]]) // N // SetPrecision[#, 3] &
maxCurrent2 = MaximalBy[dataSet2, Last][[1, 2]];
noPoints2 = Length[dataSet2];
lifeTime2 = dataSet2[[-1, 1]];

ListLinePlot[{set[1]}, PlotRange -> {{0, 700}, {0, 6}}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Directive[RGBColor[0., 0.75, 0.85], 
    AbsoluteThickness[2.5]], {set[2], set[3], 
    PlotRange -> {{0, 700, {0, 5}, 
       PlotStyle -> {Directive[RGBColor[0.4, 0.5, 0.6], 
          AbsoluteThickness[2.5]]}}}}}, PlotTheme -> "Detailed", 
 Epilog -> {{Red, AbsolutePointSize[4], Point[dataSet]}, {Dashed, 
    Line[{{262, 3.91`}, {281, 1.26`}}]}, {Purple, 
    AbsolutePointSize[4], Point[dataSet2]}, 
   Inset[Framed[
     Grid[{{Style["Cathode 284 - Drilled", 
         Bold]}, {"Average Current: ", avgCurrent, 
        " \[Mu]A"}, {"Maximum Current: ", maxCurrent, 
        " \[Mu]A"}, {"Active Cathode Lifetime: ", lifeTime, 
        "minutes"}, {"Number of Data Points: ", noPoints}}], 
     Background -> White, RoundingRadius -> 5], Scaled[{.40, .85}]], 
   Inset[Framed[
     Grid[{{Style["Cathode 285 - Undrilled", Bold, 
         TextAlignment -> Center]}, {"Average Current: ", avgCurrent2,
         " \[Mu]A"}, {"Maximum Current: ", maxCurrent2, 
        " \[Mu]A"}, {"Active Cathode Lifetime: ", lifeTime2, 
        "minutes"}, {"Number of Data Points: ", noPoints2}}], 
     Background -> White, RoundingRadius -> 5], Scaled[{.80, .85}]]}, 
 PlotLabel -> 
  "Current Yield: Drilled Iron Cathode vs. Undrilled Iron Cathode", 
 PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[LineLegend[{"Iron (Cathode 284 - Drilled)", 
     "Iron (Cathode 285 - Undrilled)"}, 
    LegendFunction -> "Panel"], {0.80, 0.28}], 
 LabelStyle -> {Black, Bold}, Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, False}},
  FrameLabel -> {"Cathode Runtime (minutes)", "Current (\[Mu]A)"}, 
 ImageSize -> {550, 550}, InterpolationOrder -> 1]
```

The target is something like this (except with 2 lines):
[image]

Currently, it outputs:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for a clear description of your on-topic goal (✅) and the well formatted, easy to *copy&paste*, in [Raw InputForm](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/menuitem/RawInputForm.html) *Wolfram Language* code example  (✅). You question would be easier to answer and more useful for future readers if it was a **minimal** working code example instead of that long piece of code with so many details irrelevant to the question. (❌)

Comment: Perhaps you want `ListLinePlot[{set[1], set[2], set[3]},...]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How's this:

```
ListLinePlot[{set[1], set[2], set[3]},
 PlotRange -> {{0, 700}, {0, 6}},
 PlotStyle -> {Directive[RGBColor[0.4, 0.5, 0.6], 
    AbsoluteThickness[2.5]],
   Directive[RGBColor[0.8, 0.5, 0.6], AbsoluteThickness[2.5]], 
   Directive[RGBColor[0.8, 0.5, 0.6], AbsoluteThickness[2.5]]},
 PlotTheme -> "Detailed",
 Epilog -> {
   {Red, AbsolutePointSize[4], Point[dataSet]}, {Dashed, 
    Line[{{262, 3.91`}, {281, 1.26`}}]},
   {Purple, AbsolutePointSize[4], Point[dataSet2]}, 
   Inset[Framed[
     Grid[{{Style["Cathode 284 - Drilled", 
         Bold]}, {"Average Current: ", avgCurrent, 
        " \[Mu]A"}, {"Maximum Current: ", maxCurrent, 
        " \[Mu]A"}, {"Active Cathode Lifetime: ", lifeTime, 
        "minutes"}, {"Number of Data Points: ", noPoints}}], 
     Background -> White, RoundingRadius -> 5], Scaled[{.40, .85}]], 
   Inset[Framed[
     Grid[{{Style["Cathode 285 - Undrilled", Bold, 
         TextAlignment -> Center]}, {"Average Current: ", avgCurrent2,
         " \[Mu]A"}, {"Maximum Current: ", maxCurrent2, 
        " \[Mu]A"}, {"Active Cathode Lifetime: ", lifeTime2, 
        "minutes"}, {"Number of Data Points: ", noPoints2}}], 
     Background -> White, RoundingRadius -> 5], Scaled[{.80, .85}]]}, 
 PlotLabel -> 
  "Current Yield: Drilled Iron Cathode vs. Undrilled Iron Cathode", 
 PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[LineLegend[{"Iron (Cathode 284 - Drilled)", 
     "Iron (Cathode 285 - Undrilled)"}, 
    LegendFunction -> "Panel"], {0.80, 0.28}], 
 LabelStyle -> {Black, Bold}, Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, False}},
  FrameLabel -> {"Cathode Runtime (minutes)", "Current (\[Mu]A)"}, 
 ImageSize -> {550, 550}, InterpolationOrder -> 1]
```

[image]

Comment: Line colors are incorrect. See my comment in the question.

Comment: Oh I see, just a minute...

Comment: There you go. Second and third plot style directives control the color of the second and third plot lines (undrilled).

Comment: This is perfect thank you. I wasn't too far off - still would've taken me days to spot what I did wrong